# Is "type" required for an input?

Tags: html, css, input

So I'm again amidst a philosophical debate;

**Should you specify a `type` for an `input` when all you want is a text input?**

The default for `type` is of course `text`, so omitting the default attribute accomplishes what you want and saves 12 bytes in markup.

However, I can't help but feel that there's something wrong with this. One real-world scenario is implementing a library such as [Formalize](http://formalize.me/); it doesn't touch elements without explicit `type`s.

The alternatives that were given to me are to either use `:not([type])` which kills IE8 support, or to apply text input styles to all `input`s and then undo them all for `submit`s and others that shouldn't look like textboxes. Both of which sound very kludgey to me when it'd be only so much simpler to just write the `type` in markup.

It also rubs me the wrong way to just *assume* that the browser will until the end of time just *know* what you mean without explicitly defining it. For example, growing up with Windows I just assumed Times New Roman was the default font on web pages everywhere. Then I installed Ubuntu and boy was I surprised.

Is it bad form to not define `type`? Are there any compelling reasons not to define it? Are there any other concerns for not specifying `type` and relying on the default than the ones I mentioned? Does this default work on older browsers? How's the accessibility on non-specific `input`s?

Comment: Just so it's noted: there are enough bytes in this question to offset the savings from a couple of years' worth of type-defaulted `<input>` elements.  I hope you're happy.  :)

Comment: I don't doubt it; and it's not me with the anti-`type` policy, but the developers of MediaWiki. And I'm sure they'll be over the moon :D

Comment: This does not look like a constructive question. What is the real problem you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` attribute is not required for an `<input>` element.  As you state, it defaults to `text`.  However despite those being the semantics defined by HTML, some tools do not respect this.  As a result, it's safer to specify it explicitly.

> It also rubs me the wrong way to just *assume* that the browser will until the end of time just *know* what you mean without explicitly defining it.

It is explicitly defined - by the HTML specifications.  An `<input>` element without a `type` attribute defaults to being of type `text`.  A browser wouldn't be rendering HTML correctly unless it handled things in this way.  The only assumption you are making is that this is unspecified behaviour.  Read the specifications.

> For example, growing up with Windows I just assumed Times New Roman was the default font on web pages everywhere.

The difference there is that there is no specification defining this to be the default.

Comment: Just adding a source:  
[W3 - Forms in HTML documents - Input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)

Comment: Is there a real-world scenario where not explicitly defining a `type` would cause problems? I mean, it's not exactly a far-fetched idea that browsers don't respect specifications. Perhaps not so much these days at least with `<input>`s, but newer specs are often just drafts and browsers interpret them in different ways, so I thought a policy of being as explicit as possible would be good form.

Comment: *"Is there a real-world scenario where not explicitly defining a type would cause problems?"* Huh?  You already gave an example - Formalize.  *"specs are often just drafts"* Again, I have to say: huh?  If a spec is a draft, it says so.  The HTML 4.01 specification is certainly not a draft, it's been stable for about 15 years.

Comment: I meant it more as a reference to your *"some tools do not respect this."*. And I've found something being a draft certainly doesn't stop vendors from implementing them; but as I said, it doesn't really apply to this question.

Comment: Formalize is an example of such a tool.  I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I see; I wouldn't really consider Formalize a "tool" more than it is a "library", and it's more of a question of practicality (first defining rules for all `input`s and then overriding them for `submit`s or something stupid like that to get to non-specific `input`s) rather than disrespect for HTML semantics, as you made it sound like :P

Answer (score 3):

According to the specification, the default type is always text, as you say.  If we are to take this is read, then this would mean that the default would 'always' be text.  I think that, for the purposes of correctness, the type should always be defined in the element, if for no other reason that readability purposes.  I also agree that specifying the type ensures no guesswork can ever be made as to the purpose of the element, and should always be used.

Having said that, do we always specify a type of 'text/javascript' when using `<script>` tags?  I know I don't all of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I would define the type-attribute everytime, because you never know what kind of libraries you will need and use in the future.

It doesn't take that much time writing 'type="text"' but it could save you a lot of time, if any external code requires it. I guess, asking the question took more time than writing the code. :)

In one project, years ago, I used to shortcut the PHP-Echo in templates. Everything worked fine until I changed the host with another PHP config, that doesn't allow shortcuts. So I had to edit my whole code just because I was too lazy the weeks before. It's just copy/paste but it's anoying when you're using Git or SVN because suddenly almost every template-file was updated.

Comment: The default input type isn't going to change out from under anyone, so that last paragraph doesn't really work very well as an example IMO.  (That said, i'd still recommend including the `type`, for readability purposes if nothing else.  But if you don't, your pages will still work for as long as browsers use HTML.)

Comment: @cHao the last paragraph should just show him, there could rise a lot of annoying work, just be because of avoiding a few lines of code. :)

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason not to include the attribute.  In terms of getting browsers to play nice, and render your pages as they were intended, it's nearly always better to be specific.  You have the control there, so why not use it?

It's also interesting that you mention the extra bytes, as it sounds as though that may be your real concern, and so I assume this is for a large-scale site.  With that said, minifying your source will net a much better result than worrying about explicitly specifying the type attribute.

Comment: Well actually, it's MediaWiki that I found this behavior in; they don't define `type` for the `input`s in their forms. And really, the only sensible reason I could come up with on why they'd do that is if they're really concerned about those extra bytes.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger With regards to the extra bytes, MediaWiki's source is actually quite interesting.  If you take a look through the source on the home page, some of it has been minified and other parts haven't.  I think you've asked an interesting question, but unless you're working on an extremely heavy-traffic site, I see no reason to abandon the attribute.  There are plenty of other optimisations to be tried before worrying about something like that.

Comment: That's what I thought, but going around MW's IRC channel, I was met with much criticism for my pie-in-the-sky notions of wanting MW to explicitly define default attributes and was told that it's not even possible to mod it to do so; or at the very least, they wouldn't offer any help in that endeavor.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger: If that's the real reason, then they're idiots.  12 bytes is a drop in a bucket; even the HTTP headers themselves often take a hundred times that.  The more likely reason they're criticizing, though, is that (a) it doesn't matter either way, as far as HTML goes, and (b) you're making a big deal about it as if it did.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `type` can be set to the following values, as of HTML5. I suggest using the correct , as mobile browser will sometimes use different keyboard forms depending on their type. But no, the world will not end if you disregard the attribute, and it's default value is text.

That being said, by not using it, it will be set to `type="text"` anyways. I, personally, always set it, even when it is set to `text`.

- button
- checkbox
- color
- date
- datetime
- datetime-local
- email
- file
- hidden
- image
- month
- number
- password
- radio
- range
- reset
- search
- submit
- tel
- text
- time
- url
- week

Answer (score -2):

The `type` attribute is not necessary, but you will want to use it for specifying wether you wan a "button","password","radio",etc.